# Change state of a checkbox with addEventListener in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox, click, addeventlistener

I'm really new to JavaScript. I'm having some issues with my JavaScript code to change the state (checked or unchecked) of my checkbox input every time I click on an anchor element (the size and content is correct in CSS).

HTML simplified

```
<section>
  <a id="trigger"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle">
</section>
```

JavaScript

```
let trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let i = document.getElementById('nav-toggle');
  if(i.checked === false) {
     i.checked = true;
  } else {
    i.checked = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Let me know if my JavaScript code make sense, and what should I fix to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just tried your code and it works fine, you've just put an extra curly brace on line 9

```js
let trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let i = document.getElementById('nav-toggle');
  if (i.checked === false) {
    i.checked = true;
  } else {
    i.checked = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<section>
  <a id="trigger">toggle</a>
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle">
</section>
```

Comment: Yeah I saw the curly brace mistake after posting but it still didn't worked when removed. BUT, I've noticed that I had 2 tags with the 'trigger' class and apparently that's why it didn't worked, but now it is! (:

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is toggle the checkbox, don't use javascript, use the HTML [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element and set the `for` attribute to the id of the checkbox.

```html
<section>
  <label for="nav-toggle"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="alternate text"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle">
</section>
```